# rewrite many subfolder to same domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, subdirectory

I have 3 system in same main folder

- joomla
- wordpress
- moodle

and i planed when

- user open mydomain.com it show joomla
- user open mydomain.com/blog it show content in wordpress
- user open mydomain.com/learn it show moodle course

impossible?

i try by many code example

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !joomla/
RewriteRule (.*) /joomla/$1
RewriteRule ^mydomain.com/learn(.*) moodle/$1
```

it can mapping joomla as domain but mydomain/learn not work. 
i think if include wordpress and moodle in joomla folder. when i update joomla by automatic script. that remove my moodle and wordpress.

Comment: Just a suggestions: rather than messing around with htaccess, why not just [move your Wordpress installation into a folder called "blog"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_Directories_On_Your_Existing_Server) and your [Moodle into a folder called "learn"](https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Moodle_migration#Migrating_a_complete_Moodle_site_-_method_1), leaving Joomla in the home directory. It's a more permanent approach.

Comment: because joomla update by delete / move all file and folder. i don't need lost other system when joomla update.